# Git no branch issue

Tags: git, github

I think I did something wrong at HEAD@{6} or HEAD@{7}. Doesn't it look strange with two checkouts? Maybe also strange at HEAD@{0}?

I'd appreciate if someone experienced could guide me through this so I don't lose data. I've seen other 'no branch' discussions, but to me this looks more complicated. I've checked in all day, but I noticed this when I tried to make a push to github.

```
eternity$ git reflog show
d15e9e7 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 09e40efea3a4831ce8cbfd2a82634e23e2013d92 to master
09e40ef HEAD@{1}: commit: Rewards points for defensive strike.
33efb7d HEAD@{2}: commit: Multiple score labels can be shown.
a548ccf HEAD@{3}: commit: Resolution in Kamcord works
0f56190 HEAD@{4}: commit: Ctrl layer msg is displayed in the center of the screen
c2b195d HEAD@{5}: commit: Added setup view in director. Resolution is still bad.
d15e9e7 HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from 0311aa9b0a2a9f26de0a8a0d95adfc2fc2e5fd9e to d15e9e7de8332dc
0311aa9 HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from master to 0311aa9b0a2a
d15e9e7 HEAD@{8}: commit: Possible to export Kamcord replay.
7225b6c HEAD@{9}: commit: Kamcord in application, but no API calls.
eef0d78 HEAD@{10}: commit: Updated AppDelegate in accordance with 1.1 RC0
b551782 HEAD@{11}: commit: OnDevice match is handled correctly in menu after app start.
e374935 HEAD@{12}: commit: Bat glow is removed upon dealloc
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what is your problem? The checkouts appear when you switch branches, rebase or sth. like that and are totally normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried 30 minutes ago I got a message stating something about I didn't have any branch. I was unable to push. But now it worked. Maybe some network problems? I've not changed anything...

Comment: "git status" helps most of the time to shed some light onto the status of your repo and why things go wrong.